# How to solve this thing with finder method and the helper paginator Cakephp3?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

i have a problem with a custom finder and the helper paginator. The problem is the following:
In my view index of graduates i have a form which points to the myFinder method on the same controller, the form contains two fields, find by first_name and last_name. When I caught the form in the method myFinder  I copy the data with a for into a array, then the array looks like this

`$data = $this->paginate($this->Graduates->find('all',['conditions' => $original]));`
when `$original` is `$original=['Graduates.first_name like'=>'%michael%','Graguates.last_name like' =>'%james%']`. The array original contains the data of the form sent by post.

So when a retrieved the data in my "myFinder" view the first number of the pagination looks fine,no problem, but when i clicked the number two, an error appears:

Could this be caused by using Auto-Tables?

Some of the Table objects in your application were created by instantiating "Cake\ORM\Table"
instead of any other specific subclass.

This could be the cause for this exception. Auto-Tables are created for you under the following circumstances:
The class for the specified table does not exist.The Table was created with a typo: TableRegistry::get('Atricles');The class file has a typo in the name or incorrect namespace: class Atricles extends TableThe file containing the class has a typo or incorrect casing: Atricles.phpThe Table was used using associations but the association has a typo: $this->belongsTo('Atricles')The table class resides in a Plugin but no plugin notation was used in the association definition.

Please try correcting the issue for the following table aliases:
Graduates.

So I think the error is when I click the second number o third . The method myFinder is called again but the form data was lost the first time. How can I solulate this problem.

Really i need help!.

Comment: you need to re-assign the fields when you click on page 2, use `$this->request->query` in if condition to check `['page']` and re-assign the fields of first and last name

Comment: What is the exact error?